# Python Library- How to update the version of my library outside the library?

Tags: python, pip, package, setup.py

I created library in python (in PyCharm) at my first time as it wrriten here:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-a-python-library-7d5aea80cc3f

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRqQw.png)

to check myself I created new project in a different path.
I ran: pip install /path/to/wheelfile.whl

and: import mypythonlib to install my library.
it succeed and i could use the library's files.

The problem:
after some days i added new classes and files under mypythonlib,
Also changed the version of my set up file from 0.1.0 to 0.2.0
and now **I can't use the new files** and classes that i added to mypythonlib.

I tried to run again  pip install /path/to/wheelfile.whl, import mypythonlib but only 0.1.0 was detected.

What can I do in order to update the library version outside the library?
i want that my users can use the updated version of my library.

edit:

I changed the version of the set up file manually

and then ran from library:
python setup.py install

python setup.py build --build-base=path_to_library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F935U.png)

Comment: Did `pip install --upgrade mypython lib` work?

Answer (score 1):

try `pip install --upgrade mypythonlib`

Comment: it is written that the requirement is up to date, it still doesn't recognize 0.2.0. maybe it's related to the fact that i created virtual environment?

Comment: Did you build your library again? as mentioned in step 5 of https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-a-python-library-7d5aea80cc3f

Answer (score 1):

ok the solution is:

1. If I add files to my library i need to change my library version in the set up file (for example from 0.1.0 to 0.1.2)
2. i need to activate again my environment (!). i forgot to do that.
3. run :  python setup.py bdist_wheel
4. My users need to run in their environment:   (in order to install the updated version)

pip install pth to lib\dist\pythonlib-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl

5. the new whl is replacing the last one